# Autogenerar Clave primaria para una Entidad y SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, java-ee, jboss

Tengo un proyecto donde hago persistencia a través de Entidades java, que apuntan a tablas de una base de datos SQLServer, pero solo puedo insertar una con mi entityManager, ya que inserta con el ID 0, y cuando quiero insertar otra, me pone que viola las restricciones de la clave primaria.

He probado a añadir la anotación `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)`, pero parece ser que una entidad en SQLServer no soporta esas anotaciones, me genera la siguiente traza:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1683)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1187)
        at es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.interfaz.web.InterfazController.sacarString(InterfazController.java:138)
        at es.xunta.amtega.vp301b.interfaz.web.InterfazController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3a2d1d25.invoke(<generated>)
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
        at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:62)
        ... 90 more
     Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:129)
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:211)
        at org.hibernate.id.IdentityGenerator$GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(IdentityGenerator.java:96)
        at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:492)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:197)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:181)
        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:216)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:334)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:289)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:195)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:126)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1181)
        ... 96 more
     Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ID', table 'AvanteDXXS_Pruebas.dbo.CVINSTELEMATICA'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:259)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1547)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:548)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:479)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7347)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2713)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:224)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:204)
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:426)
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
        ... 117 more
```

ENTIDAD:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CVINSTELEMATICA")
public class SolicitudTelematica extends AbstractEntity{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private long idTelematica;

    @Column(name = "NUMEROMENORES", columnDefinition = "smallint")
    private int numeroMenores;

    @Column(name = "NIFTUTOR", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String nifTutor;

    @Column(name = "NOMBRETUTOR", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String nombreTutor;

    @Column(name = "APELL1TUTOR", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido1Tutor;

    @Column(name = "APELL2TUTOR", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido2Tutor;

    @Column(name = "PROVINCIA", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String provincia;

    @Column(name = "LOCALIDAD", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String localidad;

    @Column(name = "DIRECCION", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String direccion;

    @Column(name = "CODPOSTAL", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String codigoPostal;

    @Column(name = "TELFIJO", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String telefonoFijo;

    @Column(name = "TELMOVIL", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String telefonoMovil;

    @Column(name = "RELACION", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String relacion;

    @Column(name = "FAMILIANUMEROSA", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char familianumerosa;

    @Column(name = "NOMBREMENOR1", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String nombreMenor1;

    @Column(name = "APELL1MENOR1", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido1Menor1;

    @Column(name = "APELL2MENOR1", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido2Menor1;

    @Column(name = "DNIMENOR1", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String dniMenor1;

    @Column(name = "FECNACMENOR1")
    private Date fechaNacimientoMenor1;

    @Column(name = "CARNEXOVEMENOR1", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char carnetJovenMenor1;

    @Column(name = "DISCAMENOR1", columnDefinition="float")
    private float discapacidadMenor1;

    @Column(name = "NOMBREMENOR2", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String nombreMenor2;

    @Column(name = "APELL1MENOR2", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido1Menor2;

    @Column(name = "APELL2MENOR2", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido2Menor2;

    @Column(name = "DNIMENOR2", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String dniMenor2;

    @Column(name = "FECNACMENOR2")
    private Date fechaNacimientoMenor2;

    @Column(name = "CARNEXOVEMENOR2", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char carnetJovenMenor2;

    @Column(name = "DISCAMENOR2", columnDefinition="float")
    private float discapacidadMenor2;

    @Column(name = "NOMBREMENOR3", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String nombreMenor3;

    @Column(name = "APELL1MENOR3", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido1Menor3;

    @Column(name = "APELL2MENOR3", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido2Menor3;

    @Column(name = "DNIMENOR3", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String dniMenor3;

    @Column(name = "FECNACMENOR3")
    private Date fechaNacimientoMenor3;

    @Column(name = "CARNEXOVEMENOR3", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char carnetJovenMenor3;

    @Column(name = "DISCAMENOR3", columnDefinition="float")
    private float discapacidadMenor3;

    @Column(name = "NOMBREMENOR4", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String nombreMenor4;

    @Column(name = "APELL1MENOR4", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido1Menor4;

    @Column(name = "APELL2MENOR4", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String apellido2Menor4;

    @Column(name = "DNIMENOR4", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String dniMenor4;

    @Column(name = "FECNACMENOR4")
    private Date fechaNacimientoMenor4;

    @Column(name = "CARNEXOVEMENOR4", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char carnetJovenMenor4;

    @Column(name = "DISCAMENOR4", columnDefinition="float")
    private float discapacidadMenor4;

    @Column(name = "TELEMATICA", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char telematica;

    @Column(name = "EMAIL", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "CODCEN1", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String codigoCentro1;

    @Column(name = "CODCEN2", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String codigoCentro2;

    @Column(name = "CODCEN3", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String codigoCentro3;

    @Column(name = "CODCEN4", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String codigoCentro4;

    @Column(name = "CODCEN5", columnDefinition = "nvarchar")
    private String codigoCentro5;

    @Column(name = "DATOSCERTIFICADO", columnDefinition = "ntext")
    private String datosCertificado;

    @Column(name = "DATOSREXISTRO", columnDefinition = "ntext")
    private String datosRegistro;

    @Column(name = "DATAREXISTRO")
    private Date fechaRegistro;

    @Column(name = "FECHADNI")
    private Date fechaCaducidadDNI;

    @Column(name = "AUTORIZARCOMPROBACION", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char autorizarComprobacion;

    @Column(name = "AUTORIZARCOMPROBACIONDISC", columnDefinition = "nchar" )
    private char autorizarDiscapacidad;

    @Column(name = "MODALIDADE")
    private int modalidad;

    @Column(name = "FAMILIAMONOPARENTAL", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char familiaMonoparental;

    @Column(name = "AUTORIZARCOMPROBACIONCARNEXOVE", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char autorizarComprobarCarneXove;

    @Column(name = "AUTORIZARCOMPROBACIONFAMILIANUMEROSA", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char autorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa;

    @Column(name = "AUTORIZARCOMPROBACIONFAMILIAMONOPARENTAL", columnDefinition = "nchar")
    private char autorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental;


    public long getIdTelematica() {
        return idTelematica;
    }

    public void setIdTelematica(int idTelematica) {
        this.idTelematica = idTelematica;
    }

    public int getNumeroMenores() {
        return numeroMenores;
    }

    public void setNumeroMenores(int numeroMenores) {
        this.numeroMenores = numeroMenores;
    }

    public String getNifTutor() {
        return nifTutor;
    }

    public void setNifTutor(String nifTutor) {
        this.nifTutor = nifTutor;
    }

    public String getNombreTutor() {
        return nombreTutor;
    }

    public void setNombreTutor(String nombreTutor) {
        this.nombreTutor = nombreTutor;
    }

    public String getApellido1Tutor() {
        return apellido1Tutor;
    }

    public void setApellido1Tutor(String apellido1Tutor) {
        this.apellido1Tutor = apellido1Tutor;
    }

    public String getApellido2Tutor() {
        return apellido2Tutor;
    }

    public void setApellido2Tutor(String apellido2Tutor) {
        this.apellido2Tutor = apellido2Tutor;
    }

    public String getProvincia() {
        return provincia;
    }

    public void setProvincia(String provincia) {
        this.provincia = provincia;
    }

    public String getLocalidad() {
        return localidad;
    }

    public void setLocalidad(String localidad) {
        this.localidad = localidad;
    }

    public String getDireccion() {
        return direccion;
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getCodigoPostal() {
        return codigoPostal;
    }

    public void setCodigoPostal(String codigoPostal) {
        this.codigoPostal = codigoPostal;
    }

    public String getTelefonoFijo() {
        return telefonoFijo;
    }

    public void setTelefonoFijo(String telefonoFijo) {
        this.telefonoFijo = telefonoFijo;
    }

    public String getTelefonoMovil() {
        return telefonoMovil;
    }

    public void setTelefonoMovil(String telefonoMovil) {
        this.telefonoMovil = telefonoMovil;
    }

    public String getRelacion() {
        return relacion;
    }

    public void setRelacion(String relacion) {
        this.relacion = relacion;
    }

    public char getFamilianumerosa() {
        return familianumerosa;
    }

    public void setFamilianumerosa(char familianumerosa) {
        this.familianumerosa = familianumerosa;
    }

    public String getNombreMenor1() {
        return nombreMenor1;
    }

    public void setNombreMenor1(String nombreMenor1) {
        this.nombreMenor1 = nombreMenor1;
    }

    public String getApellido1Menor1() {
        return apellido1Menor1;
    }

    public void setApellido1Menor1(String apellido1Menor1) {
        this.apellido1Menor1 = apellido1Menor1;
    }

    public String getApellido2Menor1() {
        return apellido2Menor1;
    }

    public void setApellido2Menor1(String apellido2Menor1) {
        this.apellido2Menor1 = apellido2Menor1;
    }

    public String getDniMenor1() {
        return dniMenor1;
    }

    public void setDniMenor1(String dniMenor1) {
        this.dniMenor1 = dniMenor1;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimientoMenor1() {
        return fechaNacimientoMenor1;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimientoMenor1(Date fechaNacimientoMenor1) {
        this.fechaNacimientoMenor1 = fechaNacimientoMenor1;
    }

    public char getCarnetJovenMenor1() {
        return carnetJovenMenor1;
    }

    public void setCarnetJovenMenor1(char carnetJovenMenor1) {
        this.carnetJovenMenor1 = carnetJovenMenor1;
    }

    public float getDicapacidadMenor1() {
        return discapacidadMenor1;
    }

    public void setDiscapacidadMenor1(float discapacidadMenor1) {
        this.discapacidadMenor1 = discapacidadMenor1;
    }

    public String getNombreMenor2() {
        return nombreMenor2;
    }

    public void setNombreMenor2(String nombreMenor2) {
        this.nombreMenor2 = nombreMenor2;
    }

    public String getApellido1Menor2() {
        return apellido1Menor2;
    }

    public void setApellido1Menor2(String apellido1Menor2) {
        this.apellido1Menor2 = apellido1Menor2;
    }

    public String getApellido2Menor2() {
        return apellido2Menor2;
    }

    public void setApellido2Menor2(String apellido2Menor2) {
        this.apellido2Menor2 = apellido2Menor2;
    }

    public String getDniMenor2() {
        return dniMenor2;
    }

    public void setDniMenor2(String dniMenor2) {
        this.dniMenor2 = dniMenor2;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimientoMenor2() {
        return fechaNacimientoMenor2;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimientoMenor2(Date fechaNacimientoMenor2) {
        this.fechaNacimientoMenor2 = fechaNacimientoMenor2;
    }

    public char getCarnetJovenMenor2() {
        return carnetJovenMenor2;
    }

    public void setCarnetJovenMenor2(char carnetJovenMenor2) {
        this.carnetJovenMenor2 = carnetJovenMenor2;
    }

    public float getDiscapacidadMenor2() {
        return discapacidadMenor2;
    }

    public void setDiscapacidadMenor2(float discapacidadMenor2) {
        this.discapacidadMenor2 = discapacidadMenor2;
    }

    public String getNombreMenor3() {
        return nombreMenor3;
    }

    public void setNombreMenor3(String nombreMenor3) {
        this.nombreMenor3 = nombreMenor3;
    }

    public String getApellido1Menor3() {
        return apellido1Menor3;
    }

    public void setApellido1Menor3(String apellido1Menor3) {
        this.apellido1Menor3 = apellido1Menor3;
    }

    public String getApellido2Menor3() {
        return apellido2Menor3;
    }

    public void setApellido2Menor3(String apellido2Menor3) {
        this.apellido2Menor3 = apellido2Menor3;
    }

    public String getDniMenor3() {
        return dniMenor3;
    }

    public void setDniMenor3(String dniMenor3) {
        this.dniMenor3 = dniMenor3;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimientoMenor3() {
        return fechaNacimientoMenor3;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimientoMenor3(Date fechaNacimientoMenor3) {
        this.fechaNacimientoMenor3 = fechaNacimientoMenor3;
    }

    public char getCarnetJovenMenor3() {
        return carnetJovenMenor3;
    }

    public void setCarnetJovenMenor3(char carnetJovenMenor3) {
        this.carnetJovenMenor3 = carnetJovenMenor3;
    }

    public float getDiscapacidadMenor3() {
        return discapacidadMenor3;
    }

    public void setDiscapacidadMenor3(float discapacidadMenor3) {
        this.discapacidadMenor3 = discapacidadMenor3;
    }

    public String getNombreMenor4() {
        return nombreMenor4;
    }

    public void setNombreMenor4(String nombreMenor4) {
        this.nombreMenor4 = nombreMenor4;
    }

    public String getApellido1Menor4() {
        return apellido1Menor4;
    }

    public void setApellido1Menor4(String apellido1Menor4) {
        this.apellido1Menor4 = apellido1Menor4;
    }

    public String getApellido2Menor4() {
        return apellido2Menor4;
    }

    public void setApellido2Menor4(String apellido2Menor4) {
        this.apellido2Menor4 = apellido2Menor4;
    }

    public String getDniMenor4() {
        return dniMenor4;
    }

    public void setDniMenor4(String dniMenor4) {
        this.dniMenor4 = dniMenor4;
    }

    public Date getFechaNacimientoMenor4() {
        return fechaNacimientoMenor4;
    }

    public void setFechaNacimientoMenor4(Date fechaNacimientoMenor4) {
        this.fechaNacimientoMenor4 = fechaNacimientoMenor4;
    }

    public char getCarnetJovenMenor4() {
        return carnetJovenMenor4;
    }

    public void setCarnetJovenMenor4(char carnetJovenMenor4) {
        this.carnetJovenMenor4 = carnetJovenMenor4;
    }

    public float getDiscapacidadMenor4() {
        return discapacidadMenor4;
    }

    public void setDiscapacidadMenor4(float discapacidadMenor4) {
        this.discapacidadMenor4 = discapacidadMenor4;
    }

    public char getTelematica() {
        return telematica;
    }

    public void setTelematica(char telematica) {
        this.telematica = telematica;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCodigoCentro1() {
        return codigoCentro1;
    }

    public void setCodigoCentro1(String codigoCentro1) {
        this.codigoCentro1 = codigoCentro1;
    }

    public String getCodigoCentro2() {
        return codigoCentro2;
    }

    public void setCodigoCentro2(String codigoCentro2) {
        this.codigoCentro2 = codigoCentro2;
    }

    public String getCodigoCentro3() {
        return codigoCentro3;
    }

    public void setCodigoCentro3(String codigoCentro3) {
        this.codigoCentro3 = codigoCentro3;
    }

    public String getCodigoCentro4() {
        return codigoCentro4;
    }

    public void setCodigoCentro4(String codigoCentro4) {
        this.codigoCentro4 = codigoCentro4;
    }

    public String getCodigoCentro5() {
        return codigoCentro5;
    }

    public void setCodigoCentro5(String codigoCentro5) {
        this.codigoCentro5 = codigoCentro5;
    }

    public String getDatosCertificado() {
        return datosCertificado;
    }

    public void setDatosCertificado(String datosCertificado) {
        this.datosCertificado = datosCertificado;
    }

    public String getDatosRegistro() {
        return datosRegistro;
    }

    public void setDatosRegistro(String datosRegistro) {
        this.datosRegistro = datosRegistro;
    }

    public Date getFechaRegistro() {
        return fechaRegistro;
    }

    public void setFechaRegistro(Date fechaRegistro) {
        this.fechaRegistro = fechaRegistro;
    }

    public Date getFechaCaducidadDNI() {
        return fechaCaducidadDNI;
    }

    public void setFechaCaducidadDNI(Date fechaCaducidadDNI) {
        this.fechaCaducidadDNI = fechaCaducidadDNI;
    }

    public char getAutorizarComprobacion() {
        return autorizarComprobacion;
    }

    public void setAutorizarComprobacion(char autorizarComprobacion) {
        this.autorizarComprobacion = autorizarComprobacion;
    }

    public char getAutorizarDiscapacidad() {
        return autorizarDiscapacidad;
    }

    public void setAutorizarDiscapacidad(char autorizarDiscapacidad) {
        this.autorizarDiscapacidad = autorizarDiscapacidad;
    }

    public int getModalidad() {
        return modalidad;
    }

    public void setModalidad(int modalidad) {
        this.modalidad = modalidad;
    }

    public char getFamiliaMonoparental() {
        return familiaMonoparental;
    }

    public void setFamiliaMonoparental(char familiaMonoparental) {
        this.familiaMonoparental = familiaMonoparental;
    }

    public char getAutorizarComprobarCarneXove() {
        return autorizarComprobarCarneXove;
    }

    public void setAutorizarComprobarCarneXove(char autorizarComprobarCarneXove) {
        this.autorizarComprobarCarneXove = autorizarComprobarCarneXove;
    }

    public char getAutorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa() {
        return autorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa;
    }

    public void setAutorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa(
            char autorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa) {
        this.autorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa = autorizarComprobarFamiliaNumerosa;
    }

    public char getAutorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental() {
        return autorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental;
    }

    public void setAutorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental(
            char autorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental) {
        this.autorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental = autorizarComprobarFamiliaMonoparental;
    }


}
```

Es posible que pueda controlar eso desde el EntityManager?

Comment: Añade el código de la entidad, para que veamos las etiquetas

Comment: @PabloLozano Acabo de añadir la entidad.

Comment: Pues en principio `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` debería ser lo más seguro, ya que Hibernate elige según el gestor de base de datos lo más apropiado (y estoy seguro que es capaz de reconocer SQL Server). Puedes probar también con `GenerationType.IDENTITY`, a ver ...

Comment: @PabloLozano Al usar esas anotaciones me dice que no se tolera la inserción de Null en un campo de primary key, incluso tenienod el NotNull. En la página de microsoft sobre el uso de sqlserver para esto, me dice que use un contador para saber siempre el número de fila a insertar, es mi solución temporal, pero dudo que no exista una manera mucho más eficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la propia documentación de SQLServer dice que debe asignarse el id teniendo en cuenta los registros insertados en una columna...Me parece un fallo muy grande del lenguaje, pero pondré igualmente un ejemplo:

Suponiendo que la entidad es SolicitudTelematica:

```
public static long contarFilas(EntityManager em){

        CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Long> cq = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root<SolicitudTelematica> root=cq.from(SolicitudTelematica.class);
        cq.multiselect(cb.count(root)); 
        return em.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
}
```

Esta sería una de las formas, insertando en la siguiente posición al asignar de id el resultado de esta función +1